# Dynamically Adding Table Rows Using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a footer row which is used to add new rows to an HTML table. For some reason when I add a new row it deletes the footer row. I want the new row to be added before the footer.

Example:

```
Row 1 
Row 2
Row 3
Footer Row with Add new row button
```

When the add button is clicked it should look like this:

```
Row 1 
Row 2
Row 3
New Row added 
Footer Row
```

Here is my code:

```
function addAddHocRow(tr) {

    $('#tblBuilder_Body tr:last').before(tr); 
}
```

tr is passed from the button click method. The above code removes the footer row.

The tr comes from the link button which is added as a column of the html table dynamically.

```
function addAddHocRowLink(td) {

    var addLink = $("<a/>").click(function() {

        addAddHocRow($(td).parent());

     }).text("Add"); 

    $(td).append(addLink); 
}
```

Actually I am making a new TR object and then populating the TD's. Each td has certain element like checkbox, dropdownlist etc. And after that the tr is added to the table.

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is some code that shows how the tds are populated.

```
var addHocRowTds = $(addHocRow).find('td');
 // append add button
    addAddHocRowLink(addHocRowTds[6]);
```

Comment: Are you sure the `tr` is correct ? It could break the markup and make you footer seem to dissapear...

Comment: Are you able to post the markup for what the `tr` variable represents?

Comment: Actually you are right if I use <tr></tr> in before it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cMJ2e/1/

Comment: Thanks but as you can mine is a little more complicated. I use td.parent() to refer to the tr row.